# Generate Chart in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, php, phtml

I have this query in my .phtml file.

```
//Retrieve the read connection
$readConnection     = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$sql = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%d-%m-%Y') AS order_date,COUNT(entity_id) AS total_orders 
        FROM sales_flat_order
        WHERE DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y-%m-%d') >= '2018-01-01'
        GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y-%m-%d')";
$result = $readConnection->fetchAll($sql);
```

I want to generate chart using this data without install any extension.

```
    +---------------+--------------+
    | Order Date    | Total orders |
    +---------------+--------------+
    | 01-01-2018    | 287          |
    +---------------+--------------+
    | 05-01-2018    | 125          |
    +---------------+--------------+
    | 07-01-2018    | 27           |
    +---------------+--------------+
    | 10-01-2018    | 75           |
    +---------------+--------------+
```

Can I do it..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following method for generate charts.

It may helpful to anyone.

```
$readConnection     = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$sql = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%d-%m-%Y') AS order_date,COUNT(entity_id) AS total_orders 
        FROM sales_flat_order
        WHERE DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y-%m-%d') >= '2018-01-01'
        GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y-%m-%d') 
        ORDER BY total_orders DESC
        LIMIT 5";
$result = $readConnection->fetchAll($sql);
$content = "<table style='border-spacing: 8px;border: 2px solid #f3a1a1;'>";
foreach($result as $row)
{
    $arr[$row['order_date']] =$row['total_orders'];
    $content .= "<tr style='background-color: #f5d5d9;'><td>".$row['order_date']."</td><td>".$row['total_orders']."</td></tr>";
}
$content .= "</table>";
foreach($arr as $arrval=>$arrkey)
{
    $incarr.= "['".$arrval ."',". $arrkey ."],";
}
$content .='<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">';
    $data = 'google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ["Date", "Orders per Day"],'.$incarr.'])';
          $content.='google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
          var options = {
          title: "Order Statistics",
          width: 900,
    height: 450,
          is3D: true,
          pieSliceText: "value",
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById("piechart"));
         chart.draw('.$data.', options);
      }
</script>';
$content.="<div id='piechart' style='width: 900px; height: 500px;align:center'></div><br/>";
echo $content;
```

Output will be :
[image]